# Group time-series-like data by same values on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, time-series

I have a large table with structure like this (`value: integer`; `created_at: timestamp with time zone`)

```
| val | created_at          |
|:----|:--------------------|
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:39 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:40 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:41 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:43 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:46 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:48 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:52 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:54 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:58 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:59 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 |
```

I want to group up records with same values and get lowest and highest `created_at` for each interval like this.

Also I need to handle intervals with only 1 record correctly (like at the start and at the end of the table)

```
| val | created_from        | created_to          |
|:----|:--------------------|:--------------------|
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:39 | 2021-01-05 13:07:43 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:46 | 2021-01-05 13:07:52 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:54 | 2021-01-05 13:07:59 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 |
```

How can I achieve this in 1 SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to eliminate records in the middle of each constant interval. We get all records with different `val` comparing to next or prev record using [lead and lag functions](https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/lead-and-lag-function-in-postgresql/)

```
select
    *
from
(select
    lag(val) over (order by created_at) prev_val,
    val,
    lead(val) over (order by created_at) next_val,

    created_at

from tbl
order by created_at) t
where (
    prev_val isnull
    or next_val isnull
    or val != next_val
    or val != prev_val
)
```

```
| prev_val | val | next_val | created_at          |
|:---------|:----|:---------|:--------------------|
| NULL     | 1   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 |
| 1        | 2   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 |
| 2        | 1   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:39 |
| 1        | 1   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:43 |
| 1        | 2   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:46 |
| 2        | 2   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:52 |
| 2        | 1   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:54 |
| 1        | 1   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:59 |
| 1        | 2   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 |
| 2        | 1   | NULL     | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 |
```

So, here we have ends of each constant interval. Also we have records for single point intervals.

Next, we need to combine left and right ends of each interval.

```
select
    val,
    (case when prev_val_2 = val then prev_created_at_2 else created_at end) as created_from,
    created_at as created_to
from
(select
    lag(val) over (order by created_at) prev_val_2,
    val,
    lead(val) over (order by created_at) next_val_2,

    lag(created_at) over (order by created_at) prev_created_at_2,
    created_at
from
(select
    lag(val) over (order by created_at) prev_val,
    val,
    lead(val) over (order by created_at) next_val,
    created_at
from tbl
order by created_at) t
where (
    (prev_val isnull
    or next_val isnull
    or val != next_val
    or val != prev_val)
)) tt
where val != next_val_2 or next_val_2 isnull
```

```
| val | created_from        | created_to          |
|:----|:--------------------|:--------------------|
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:39 | 2021-01-05 13:07:43 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:07:46 | 2021-01-05 13:07:52 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:07:54 | 2021-01-05 13:07:59 |
| 2   | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 | 2021-01-05 13:08:01 |
| 1   | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 | 2021-01-05 13:08:04 |
```

Explanation of `(case when prev_val_2 = val then prev_created_at_2 else created_at end)` expression:

We have two cases: single-point-interval like this

```
| prev_val | val | next_val | created_at          |
|:---------|:----|:---------|:--------------------|
| NULL     | 1   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:23 |
| 1        | 2   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:29 |  <--
```

and many-points-interval like this

```
| prev_val | val | next_val | created_at          |
|:---------|:----|:---------|:--------------------|
| 2        | 1   | 1        | 2021-01-05 13:07:39 |  <--
| 1        | 1   | 2        | 2021-01-05 13:07:43 |  <--
```

Condition `lag(val) = val` (`prev_val_2 = val`) stands for the second case (`1=1`), so here we take `lag(created_at)` (`prev_created_at_2`) as `created_from`: `2021-01-05 13:07:39`.

Condition `lag(val) != val` (`1!=2`) stands for the first case, so
here we take `created_at` as both `created_to` and `created_from`: `2021-01-05 13:07:29`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yet, when you put "prev_val_2 != val" clause you do not need to use "(case when prev_val_2 = val then prev_created_at_2 else created_at end)" clause, or am I missing something?

Comment: @UmutTEKİN I mean, we need to check if `prev_val_2 = val` to distinct two cases: single-point-interval and many-points-interval. I've updated explanation, hope it becomes more clear.